# Array no modifica sus datos despúes de llamar a una función C++

Tags: c++, array, programación-funcional

Estoy haciendo un programa sencillo que trata los árboles generales como árboles binarios en C++ sobre consola; el usuario puede insertar nodos escribiendo la 'dirección' del nodo padre utilizando la notación decimal Dewey (1.2, 1.1.1 y así). Entonces para encontrar la dirección de ese nodo estoy capturando todo lo que escribe el usuario en variable tipo string, trato de separar cada número y guardarlo en una posición de un vector. Ejemplo: si el usuario escribe 1.2.3 debo crear un vector con los elementos [1][2][3].

El caso es que estoy teniendo problemas para hacer que el vector guarde los valores. Les adjunto el código que hace la captura y el split de los números. La función en donde creo el vector y llamo a la función para asignar los números es main, y desde ahí llamo a obtenerDireccion().

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void obtenerDireccion(string dir, int *aux,int tam);

int main(){
    string dir; // String para guardar la dirección del nodo
    cout<<"\n\tEscribe la direccion del nodo padre:"<<endl;   
    getline(cin,dir); // la cadena debe tener la forma (n(.)?)* donde n representa un número

    int nivel = 0;  // nivel guarda el número de elementos separados por puntos que ingresa el usuario
    int *aux; // vector que guarda la dirección del nodo padre separada en  números enteros

    for(int j=0;j<dir.length();j++){
        if(dir.at(j)=='.'){
            nivel++;
        }
    }
    nivel++;

    aux = new int[nivel];
    cout<<"antes de llamar a obtenerDireccion()"<<endl;
    for(int k=0;k<nivel;k++){
        cout<<"..."<<aux[nivel];
    }
    cout<<endl;

    obtenerDireccion(dir,aux,nivel);

    cout<<"despues de llamar a la función..."<<endl;
    for(int k=0;k<nivel;k++){
        cout<<"..."<<aux[nivel];
    }
    cout<<endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void obtenerDireccion(string dir, int *aux,int tam){
    string string_temporal = "";
    int numAux;
    int posString = 0; // posición de la cadena dir
    int posVector = 0; // posición del vector que guarda los números

    while(posString<dir.length()){
        if(dir.at(posString)=='.'){
            numAux = atoi(string_temporal.c_str()); // convertir el string en un número
            aux[posVector] = numAux;
            posVector++; // avanzar a la siguiente posición de aux
            string_temporal = ""; // borrar el valor de la cadena temporal
        }else{ // si es un número
            string_temporal.push_back(dir.at(posString));       
        }
        posString++;
    }
    numAux = atoi(string_temporal.c_str()); // convertir el string en un número
    aux[posVector] = numAux;
    cout<<"valor: "<<aux[posVector]<<endl;
    // mostrando el vector dentro de la función
    for(int k=0;k<tam;k++){
        cout<<"..."<<aux[k];
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
```

Cuando ejecuto este código y escribo una cadena como la de los ejemplos, mientras estoy en la función obtenerDireccion(...) y muestro los valores del vector, estos aparecen de forma correcta, pero cuando regreso a main y trato de imprimir el vector todos los valores aparecen como 0, como si no hubiera llamado a la otra función. Leí que los array se pasan por referencia, entonces al pasarlo a la función estoy trabajando sobre el array original y no una copia, y por lo mismo los valores deberían cambiarse cuando muestro el vector en main, pero no se que esté haciendo mal...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cout<<"despues de llamar a la función..."<<endl;
for(int k=0;k<nivel;k++){
    cout<<"..."<<aux[nivel];
}
```

Fíjate que iteras sobre la variable `k` ... pero imprimes `aux[nivel]`. Si lo reemplazas por `aux[k]` verás que el array tiene los valores esperados.

El copypaste es muy malo para la salud del programador de C++

Comment: ¡Gracias! Por estar revisando la función por creer que el error estaba ahí no me había fijado en eso ...